# Why callback a called immediately when passed to Widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I have created a Custom Widget `MyTimer` in which I have passed a callback function which have to be called when it gets completed as shown in screenshot

[image]

Here is my MyTimer class code:

```
 class MyTimer extends StatefulWidget {
  VoidCallback callback;
  MyTimer(this.callback);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new MyTimerState();
}
```

But as page loads it is called automatically. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a function reference, not the result of a function call

```
new MyTimer(() => gameOver())
```

Without `() =>` `gameOver()` is executed and the result is passed to `new MyTimer(...)`